# how do I get rid of the 'go to my location icon' on google maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to display the user's current location, but without the go to my location icon on the right of the screen.

Which is achieved by calling :

```
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true)
```

Is there anything similar to the `MyLocationOverlay` from the `MapView` api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is exceptionally confusing. I am going to interpret it as "how do I get rid of the 'go to my location icon'".

In that case, try calling `getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false)` on your `GoogleMap` object.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried animateto function

```
MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        MapController mc = mapView.getController();
        String coordinates[] = {"currentLat", "currentLat"};
        double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
        double lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);

        p = new GeoPoint(
            (int) (lat * 1E6), 
            (int) (lng * 1E6));

        mc.animateTo(p);
        mc.setZoom(17);  //Your zoom level in int
        mapView.invalidate();
```

Comment: Its a different API, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

MapView is soon to be deprecated.

Comment: Sorry mate. I never noticed it. If i find solution i will update else i shall remove my answer. Thanks for the update and not downvoting ;)...

Comment: and thank you for answering, it could have been a good solution :)